# How do I fit a graphic exactly to an axis in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a png and an axis that I would like to lay over it. The included png needs to be exactly aligned with the axis, how can I do that?

This is my code so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]{graphics/foo.png}};
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.45\textwidth,
    height=0.3\textwidth
    ]
      \addplot [semithick, black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks, forget plot]
      table {
      0.5 -0.111104291472242
      1.5 -0.0789021132376754
      2.5 -0.0193816275901278
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can I use an anchor or a scope or sth to do this?

Comment: pgfplots come with an `\addplot ... graphics {...}` option for these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned, `pgfplots` knows `\addplot graphics` for this.

Here, the important things are:

You have to give the options `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax` to let `pgfplots` know, what coordinates are covered by the picture. Example:

```
\addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=-0.12,ymax=0] {example-image.png};
```

Furthermore, for the `axis` environment the options `scale only axis`, `enlargelimits`,  and `axis on top` are important. With the first, `width` and `height` are use to scale the axis rectangle only instead of the whole plot. Without `enlargelimits=false` the picture will not cover the whole axis rectangle. And `axis on top` make sure, that ticks and grids are not covered by the picture.

Here is a little showcase for these options:

[image]

Remark: in the fourth example, `axis on top` could be omitted without changing the result. But if grids are used, they wouldn't be visible on the picture then.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \node{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png}};
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.3\textwidth,
    height=0.2\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top
  ]
% with dimensions from table
%    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-0.111104291472242,ymax=-0.0193816275901278] {example-image.png};
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=-0.12,ymax=0] {example-image.png};
    \addplot [semithick, black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks, forget plot]
      table {
        0.5 -0.111104291472242
        1.5 -0.0789021132376754
        2.5 -0.0193816275901278
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
axis:\\
\texttt{scale only axis\\
enlargelimits=false\\
axis on top}\\
graphics:\\
\texttt{xmin=0,xmax=3,\\
ymin=-0.12,ymax=0}\\
\mbox{}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \node{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png}};
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.3\textwidth,
    height=0.2\textwidth,
%    scale only axis,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top
  ]
% with dimensions from table
%    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-0.111104291472242,ymax=-0.0193816275901278] {example-image.png};
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=-0.12,ymax=0] {example-image.png};
    \addplot [semithick, black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks, forget plot]
      table {
        0.5 -0.111104291472242
        1.5 -0.0789021132376754
        2.5 -0.0193816275901278
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
axis:\\
\texttt{enlargelimits=false\\
axis on top}\\
graphics:\\
\texttt{xmin=0,xmax=3,\\
ymin=-0.12,ymax=0}\\
\mbox{}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \node{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png}};
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.3\textwidth,
    height=0.2\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
    enlargelimits=false,
%    axis on top
  ]
% with dimensions from table
%    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-0.111104291472242,ymax=-0.0193816275901278] {example-image.png};
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=-0.12,ymax=0] {example-image.png};
    \addplot [semithick, black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks, forget plot]
      table {
        0.5 -0.111104291472242
        1.5 -0.0789021132376754
        2.5 -0.0193816275901278
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
axis:\\
\texttt{scale only axis\\
enlargelimits=false}\\
graphics:\\
\texttt{xmin=0,xmax=3,\\
ymin=-0.12,ymax=0}\\
\mbox{}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \node{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png}};
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.3\textwidth,
    height=0.2\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
%    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top
  ]
% with dimensions from table
%    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-0.111104291472242,ymax=-0.0193816275901278] {example-image.png};
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=-0.12,ymax=0] {example-image.png};
    \addplot [semithick, black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks, forget plot]
      table {
        0.5 -0.111104291472242
        1.5 -0.0789021132376754
        2.5 -0.0193816275901278
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
axis:\\
\texttt{scale only axis\\
axis on top}\\
graphics:\\
\texttt{xmin=0,xmax=3,\\
ymin=-0.12,ymax=0}\\
\mbox{}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \node{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.png}};
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.3\textwidth,
    height=0.2\textwidth,
    scale only axis,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top
  ]
% with dimensions from table
    \addplot graphics[xmin=0.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=-0.111104291472242,ymax=-0.0193816275901278] {example-image.png};
%    \addplot graphics[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=-0.12,ymax=0] {example-image.png};
    \addplot [semithick, black, mark=x, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks, forget plot]
      table {
        0.5 -0.111104291472242
        1.5 -0.0789021132376754
        2.5 -0.0193816275901278
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedright
axis:\\
\texttt{scale only axis\\
enlargelimits=false\\
axis on top}\\
graphics:\\
\texttt{xmin=0.5,xmax=2.5,\\
ymin=-0.11110...,ymax=-0.01938...}\\
\mbox{}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```